# Positive application and continuity

Tags: functional-analysis

Be $X$ and $Y$ two compact Hausdorff spaces, we will say that an application $T: C (X; \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow C (Y; \mathbb{R})$ is positive if for every function $f \ge 0$ we have that $T (f) \ge 0$.

$C (X; \mathbb{R})$: functions defined on $X$, a compact Hausdorff space, which are continuous and bounded, with norm $||f||_\infty=\sup_{x\in X}|f(x)|$

Show that if the application $T: C (X; \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow C (Y; \mathbb{R})$  is a positive linear application, then $T$ is a continuous application.

My ideas:

$T: C (X; \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow C (Y; \mathbb{R})$

$\qquad\qquad f\longrightarrow T(f)=T(f(y))$

P.D:

$\exists M>0$ such that $||T(f)||_\infty \le M||f||_\infty$

Now, $||T(f)||_\infty=||T(\frac{f}{f})f||_\infty=||T(1)f||_\infty=||T(1)||_\infty ||f||_\infty$, where $1$ is the function constant defined by $1:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t $1(x)=1$

$||T(f)||_\infty=||T(1)||_\infty||f||_\infty$, let $M=||T(1)||_\infty>0$.
Finally, $||T(f)||_\infty= M||f||_\infty$.

Therefore, T is bounded $\Rightarrow$ T is continuous.

Is correct my proof?

And other question:

The other part of the problem is to prove that $||T(1)||_{\infty}=||T||$ where $1$ is the function constant defined by $1:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t $1(x)=1$

$||T(1)||_{\infty}\le ||T||||1||_{\infty}=||T||\Rightarrow ||T(1)||_{\infty}\le||T||$

The other side: $||T||\le||T(1)||_{\infty}$

Let $||f||_{\infty}\le 1$, with $f\ge 0,\forall x\in X$.

Now $|f(x)|\le||f||_{\infty}\le 1\Rightarrow 1\ge |f(x)|=f(x),\forall x\in X$

$\Rightarrow  f(x)\le 1\Rightarrow 0\le 1-f(x)\Rightarrow 0\le 1-f $

With $T$ positive we have that $0\le T(1-f)=T(1)-T(f)\Rightarrow T(f)\le T(1)$

Therefore,
$\sup_{x\in X}|T(f)(x)|\le \sup_{x\in X}|T(1)(x)|\Rightarrow ||T(f)||_{\infty}\le||T(1)||_{\infty}$.

Finally,

$||T||=\sup_{||f||_{\infty}=1}||T(f)||_{\infty}\le||T(1)||_{\infty}\Rightarrow ||T||\le ||T(1)||_{\infty}$.

We conclude that $||T||=||T(1)||_{\infty}$

Comment: Your proof fails to be correct when you state $||T(f)||_\infty=\sup_{y\in Y}|T(f(y)).\frac{f(y)}{f(y)}|$.  We have $f\in C(X;\mathbb R)$, so $f(y)$ with $y\in Y$ does not make sense (in general).

Comment: Also, the next equality is not correct, mostly because $T(f(y))$ does not make sense.  $T$ acts on $f$, not on $f(y)$ for $y\in Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since positive elements span $C(X;\mathbb R)$, you need only check that $T$ is bounded on the set of positive functions.  (For if $\|Tf\|\leq M\|f\|$ for $f\geq 0$, then for arbitrary $f$ we have $\|Tf\|=\|Tf^+-Tf^-\|\leq M\|f^+\|+M\|f^-\|\leq2M\|f\|$.)

Assume the opposite.  Then you obtain a sequence of positive functions $\{f_n\}$ in $C(X;\mathbb R)$ such that $\|f_n\|\leq1$ while $\|Tf_n\|\geq4^n$.  Then $f=\sum_n2^{-n}f_n$ is positive, and $f\geq2^{-n}f_n$ for all $n$, so $Tf\geq 2^{-n}Tf_n$ and thus
$$\|Tf\|\geq2^{-n}\|Tf_n\|\geq2^n$$
for all $n\in\mathbb N$, a contradiction.

Comment: Why $||Tf_n||>1$?

Comment: If $T$ is not bounded, then for each $M>0$ there exists $f\neq0$ such that $M\|f\|<\|Tf\|$.  Apply this with $M>2^{n}$ to obtain $\tilde f_n$ with $2^n\|\tilde f_n\|<\|T\tilde f_n\|$, and put $f_n=\frac{\tilde f_n}{\|\tilde f_n\|}$.

Comment: If put $f_n=\frac{\tilde f_n}{\|\tilde f_n\|}\Rightarrow ||T(f_n)||>2^n$ with this we indicate that $2 ^ n$ is "bounded" which is false

Comment: In which part of your ideas do you use the hypothesis that X is Hausdorf compact and that the linear operator T is positive?

Comment: Let me edit my answer to make things more clear.

Comment: The contradiction is that $2^n$ is "bounded" by $||T(f)||$

Comment: Yep that's right.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and apologize if I caused any discomfort

Comment: No apology needed.  Glad to help!